Получить данные и распределить в словарь
Есть БД(sqlite3) вида

Необходимо получить все прокси, и если в описании встречается http или https распределить их на словарь. Как это должно выглядеть:
proxies = {'http': 'http://10.10.10.10:3333', 
           'https': 'https://10.10.10.10:8888'
          }

Так-же нельзя забывать, что количество прокси может быть больше, чем 2. После этого из этого словаря случайным образом выбрать один прокси, удалить ее из словаря и БД. Вроде на теории легко, остановился на словаре и не могу дальше пробраться

И что конкретно у вас не получается?

И как конкретно должен выглядеть словарь, если есть несколько прокси одного типа? Тогда по ключам http и https должны быть списки? Сначала поймите те структуры, которые у вас должны получиться.

@CrazyElf не получается как минимум создать этот список, а так да, по ключам список проксей, которые выбираются рандомом (1шт) после чего она удаляется из списка и из БД и далее используется в конкретном месте (присвоить переменной эту проксю надо)

А что там создавать то: proxies = {'http': [], 'https': []}, а дальше добавляете в эти списки элементы согласно ключа.

proxies[proxy_type].append(url)
